# KVM - graphic passthrough

Tags: kvm-virtualization

My PC have two PCIs and installed CentOS 7.

I followed this [Document about PCI Passthrough](http://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/chap-Virtualization-PCI_passthrough.html#sect-Virtualization-PCI_passthrough-AI_device_to_a_host)

I  added iommu and enabled BIOS VT-D

> grep iommu /boot/grub2/grub.cfg 
>       linux16 /vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos_vmc-root ro rd.lvm.lv=centos_vmc/swap rd.md.uuid=0eab480a:fdd4b7cf:23049706:f8baaa8b crashkernel=auto  vconsole.keymap=us rd.md.uuid=b253d03a:92df752c:0b497a9e:ca0646b2 vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.lvm.lv=centos_vmc/root rhgb quiet radeon.audio=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 **intel_iommu=on**

however, when I try to do "virsh nodedev-dettach xxx", with both pci_0000_01_00_0 or pci_0000_03_00_0. my host PC crashes directly with "BUG:unable to handle kernel paging request at ...... "

> [root@vmc ~]# virsh nodedev-list | grep pci
>
> pci_0000_01_00_0
>
> pci_0000_01_00_1
>
> pci_0000_03_00_0
>
> pci_0000_03_00_1
>
> [root@vmc ~]# virsh nodedev-detach pci_0000_01_00_0

Anyone could help to passthrough one of the video card to my KVM please?

Comment: add some relevant lines from lspci please. Have you unloaded all drivers, that could interfere? Maybe a device like the framebuffer is 'keeping' the device, or 'tries' to...

Comment: You can't passthrough the video card that the system boots with.

Comment: if I unloaded all video cards. I should be able to passthrough even if the host only have one video card? yes, I didn't unload drivers as I have two identical video cards with same vendor and product id. how to unloaded only one of them,could you give me a little hints?

Comment: oh, my PC is dell optiplex 9010. DUAL 1GB AMD RADEON HD 7470. the pci_0000_01_00_0 is one card for video and pci_0000_01_00_1 for audio. another identical card with address pci_0000_03_00_0 for video and pci_0000_03_00_1 for audio

Comment: `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235 OEM]

01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]

03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235 OEM]

03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]`